# How to add customized tokens into solr to change the indexing token behaviour

Tags: drupal, solr

It's a Drupal site with solr for search. Mainly I am not satisfied with current search result on Chinese. The tokenizer has broken the words into supposed small pieces. Most of them are reasonable. But still, it made mistakes by not treating something as a valid token either breaking it to pieces or not breaking it.

Assuming I am writing Chinese now: `big data analysis` is one word which shouldn't be broken. So my search on it should find it. Also I want people to find `AI and big data analysis training` as the first hit when they search the exact phrase `AI and big data analysis training`.

So I want a way to intervene or compensate the current tokens to make the search smarter.

Maybe there is a file in `solr` allow me to manually write these tokens down to relate them certain phrases? So every time when indexing, solr can use it as a reference.

Comment: So which tokenizer are you using? You can also use the `pf2` and `pf3` arguments for edismax to boost shingles (i.e. boost documents where those three terms appear after each other). There is also a shingle factor that allows you to merge tokens, but I'm not aware of anything that allows you to say "these four tokens after each other should be a single token".

Answer (score 0):

You different steps to achieve what you want :

1) I don't see an extremely big problem with your " over tokenization" :

*big data analysis is one word which shouldn't be broken. So my search on it should find it.* -> your search will find it even if tokenized, I understand this was an example and the actual words are chinese, but I suspect a different issue there

2) You can use the edismax[1] query parser with phrase boost at various level to boost subsequent tokens or phrases ( pf,pf2,pf3...ps,ps2,ps3...)

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html , https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-ThepsParameter